# How do I add this formatted string to a python object & ensure there aren't any duplicates

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, duplicates

I have a series of strings defined in this way:

```
    print('{x}@{y}:{z}'.format(**config['name1']))
    print('{x}@{y}:{z}'.format(**config['name2']))
```

and so on. I need to add them to a python object & ensure I check for duplicates so all the values are unique. Is it best to add them to an array and include a for loop for duplication check each time I add an entry?

Comment: Consider using `set`. It will automatically deduplicates.

Comment: great, thanks! A related question also cross-posting from another question: I used string formatting & got the info I needed as pasted above. If I have a yaml file with a lot of information, how can I use this such that I don't need to specify name1 or name2 and can instead use a for loop or something? '{x}@{y}:{z}'.format(**config['name2']) in this line of code ? Thanks for the incredible help!